# Angular JS How to Get All Values for The Same Key in the Model using ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The following is a JSON model used in Angular.

```
$scope.numbers = [
{"0":"206-000-0008","connection":"206-000-0008","1":"dandelion","topic":"dandelion"},
{"0":"206-000-0008","connection":"206-000-0008","1":"burdock","topic":"burdock"},
{"0":"206-000-0008","connection":"206-000-0008","1":"cinnamon","topic":"cinnamon"},  
{"0":"206-000-0003","connection":"206-000-0003","1":"jasmine","topic":"jasmine"},
{"0":"206-000-0003","connection":"206-000-0003","1":"mint","topic":"mint"},
{"0":"206-000-0003","connection":"206-000-0003","1":"earlgray","topic":"earlgray"}
]
```

I want to loop through the model displaying all topics that have a common "connection".
Using the sample model, the display should be:

```
206-000-0008
dandelion, burdock, cinnamon

206-000-0003
jasmine, mint, earlgray
```

I've tried the following which does not display correctly:

```
<ul><!-- outer loop begin -->
    <li ng-repeat="whatever in numbers track by $index">

        {{whatever.connection}}

        <ul data-ng-show="whatever"><!-- inner loop begin -->
            <li ng-repeat="topic in whatever.connection track by $index">

                {{whatever.topic}}                   

            </li>
        </ul><!-- inner loop end -->

    </li>
</ul><!-- outer loop end -->
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call a function in ng-repeat that generates the data in a proper format.

By iterating over the $scope.numbers array, you can generate a new object (called `result`) where each key is the `connection` and each value is the comma-separated list of `topics`. If $scope.numbers is small (e.g. < 1000 elements), you won't have to worry about performance.

I haven't tested it, but the code below should work.

In your controller:

```
$scope.groupByNumbers = function() {
    var result = {};
    var numbers = $scope.numbers;

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        var num = numbers[i];
        var value = result[num.connection];
        var topic = num.topic;
        result[num.connection] = (value) ? value + ', ' + topic : topic;
    }

    return result;
}
```

In your view:

```
<p ng-repeat="(key, value) in groupByNumbers()">
    {{key}}<br />{{value}}
</p>
```

Comment: There is an add-on called AngularUI that solved this problem. It works similar to a filter with the usage:
    
        ng-repeat="whatever in numbers|unique:'connection'"


  You can find the add-on here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: From my understanding, that filter still doesn't generate the output that the OP needs. It will filter `$scope.numbers` to have only unique `connection` values, but it won't combine the `topics` into a comma-separated list.